# How to install PHP 5.3 on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, php

I finally found a place for all the PHP 5.3 files. I have all the links, I just really don't know where else to go from having the links.

Simply doing "yum install linkshere" just gave me issues like in this screenshot:

[image]

I am getting errors exactly like that for other files which are already linked to in the command.

Even though I have the link to that type of file in the command, it gives me the issues saying it's required.

My links:
http://centos.alt.ru/pub/repository/centos/6/x86_64/php-5.3.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

Go to that link and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for "php-5.3" and you will find where it starts.

Also whenever I run the following I get :

```
rpm -Uvh http://centos.alt.ru/pub/repository/centos/6/x86_64/php-5.3.27-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

[image]

My server is running CentOS 6, and from what I have done so far and read, I have removed PHP from my server. I just don't know how to go about installing everything with the issues I am getting.

I need PHP 5.3 because the script that I have is IonCubed and it's made for 5.3. The owner is no longer reachable either to get it updated.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you want not just “PHP 5.3” (which would be satisfied by the `php-5.3.3-*` packages included in the base CentOS 6 distribution), but “a PHP 5.3.x version which is more recent than 5.3.3, and the IonCube Loader module built for that PHP version”. In this case you may look at the [IUS Community Project](http://iuscommunity.org/), which provides RPM packages for the latest upstream versions of PHP and some other software, built for RHEL (and compatible with CentOS). In particular, this repository provides a recent version of [PHP 5.3.x](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/i386/repoview/php53u.html) and [the IonCube Loader module](http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/i386/repoview/php53u-ioncube-loader.html) for that version.

Note that packages from the IUS repository have different package names (e.g., PHP 5.3.x packages are named `php53u-*`) to avoid conflicts with the base system (as described on [The SafeRepo Initiative](http://iuscommunity.org/pages/TheSafeRepoInitiative.html) page), unlike packages from `centos.alt.ru` which you tried.

Comment: The IUS Community Project worked like a charm!